# Setting sys variables in external python script

Tags: python

I have a python script that runs on a cron job. The script uses the django ORM of a related web portal for db calls. However, I am having a tough time running the script from command line. At the top of the script I have:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/david542/Desktop/project/')
from project.home.models import Title, Order
```

And when I try running the script:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
self._setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable 
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined
```

It seems I need to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` path in my python script, but how exactly would I do this?

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get an `ImportError` for the `project.home.models`... Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102330/why-do-i-need-the-django-settings-module-set#2102365) might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your project settings are in /Users/david542/Desktop/project/my_settings.py you need to set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to 'my_settings' to let Django know where it is.

To set the variable, just call your script using

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_settings python /path/to/your/script.py
```

Also, I would advise you not to hard-code the path to your project in your script but to pass it along using the PYTHONPATH environment variable, as follow:

```
PYTHONPATH="/Users/david542/Desktop/project" DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_settings python /path/to/your/script.py
```

Cheers,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Put the django app in `sys.path` and then setup the django settings environment, see here for more details: [Why do I need the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102330/why-do-i-need-the-django-settings-module-set#2102365).

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/david542/Desktop/project/')
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from project import settings
setup_environ(settings)
from project.home.models import Title, Order
```